# how to show views for particular language

Tags: views, routes, i18n-l10n

I have simple problem - there is a view that is aggregating some info and it has a link in the main menu. I'm also using i18n and would like to have that particular view only in one language, but it looks like that it's impossible to make it - I can't find any option how to make the view just in one language - the main menu item appears in both languages and I can't figure out how to disable it.
I'm using D7 and newest Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use filters? When you create your view, you add a new filter and select "Node translation" from the "Groupes" list and the check "Node translation: Language" and click "Add". Then you can chose language(s) on which you want the view to show

Comment: Yes, I can filter it away and therefore the content of it is not shown on any other languages. But the problem is that the menu link is still there and it is not translated - is on my original language. If I use filters then I have this link and clicking on him while being on some other language I'm getting an empty (filtered page). So let's say it's ok - I will have content for all the languages, but how can I translate the View's name to be seen in the correct language and is it possible to hide it in general?

Comment: Maybe you can try to use one different menu for each language?That's the solution we have used on one of our project with 3 different languages : each language has his own menu , then we add a block for each menu and we select the language in which this block will appear so only one menu would display for each language but others will be hidden

Comment: we used menu-translation and menu-block modules for that ..

Comment: Well it could be a solution, I have done this in my previous project, but I think there should be something more simple - it's ok if I use one View, but if I would like to use couple different views it could be very complicated. I'm pretty sure, that there should be some other workaround, or maybe something in views functionality that I don't know.

Comment: At the end I've solved this issue by creating separate menus for different languages. Actually there is another more intelligent solution, but it is not working with D7/Views3 - it's called i18nViews (Internationalization Views) - with this it is possible to translate headings of views, but I had to disable it as it crashes the system at the moment. 

Now I have another problem - when I have two different menus for each language for some reason the menu title that is clicked is not highlighted and I can't find why...

Comment: I have never worked using i18nViews but I will have a look at it..it seems to be really interesting..have you reported the bug so they can fix it?